# Erro na criação da tabela SQL Server com Entity Framework

Tags: c#

Exclui uma tabela do meu projeto direto no Management Studio. Agora quando executo a aplicação está retorno este erro:

> ```
> system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception: Nome de objeto 'dbo.ContasPagarParcelas' inválido.
> ```

Não consigo recriar a tabela. Estou utilizando Entity Framework.

Comment: Você removeu a tabela do banco de dados mas não removeu do contexto do EF. Caso tenha duvida de como fazer isso, poste em sua pergunta o código do seu contexto, onde você define o DbSet da tabela que removeu.

Comment: Rodrigo, na verdade quero que a tabela seja recriada. Exclui direto no banco para ver o comportamento que o Entity teria ao executar o sistema novamente. Acreditava que a tabela seria recriada novamente.

Comment: Pelo que entendi na sua reposta, remover do contexto seria no caso de não utilizar mais está tabela, correto ?.

Comment: Voce deve usar CodeFrist, e deve fazer o migration, certo? se você cria migrations, apague os arquivos de migração, e mande criar um novamente. Se não funcionar, no seu banco de dados tem uma tabela com o histórico de migrações, você deve apagala

Comment: Rodrigo, consegui resolver como suas orientações. Muito obrigado.

Comment: òtimo, fico feliz. Se você puder clicar na setinha laranja do meu comentario, que fica ao lado esquerdo, eu agradeço, pois pontua minha ajuda. vlw!

Comment: Rodrigo, desculpe não encontro a setinha laranja.

Comment: Quando você passa o mouse sobre a minha mensagem, do lado esquerdo aparece uma triangulo, só clicar nele.

Comment: Coloquei, como resposta, ai você pode clicar no V, que fica ao lado esquerdo da resposta, desta forma obedecemos o fluxo do site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voce deve usar CodeFrist, e deve fazer o migration, certo? se você cria migrations, apague os arquivos de migração, e mande criar um novamente.

Se não funcionar, no seu banco de dados tem uma tabela com o histórico de migrações, você deve apagala